# VBA webpage automation: click radio button in next TD with reference to previous TD without ID

Tags: html, vba, automation, browser-automation, webautomation

I'm trying to automatically click a radio button on a webpage. Here's the relevant HTML code:

```
<TD width="25%"><SPAN>RW B</SPAN></TD>

<TD width="15%"><INPUT onclick="SetAccessLevel('B','RW');" id=Ctrl_59296626_ctl95 type=radio value=ctl95 name=Ctrl_59296626$GroupAccess></TD>
```

I want to click the radio button in the second TD.

I can't use the element ID because I intend to use the same macro on other webpages of the same type where the ID and value differ but the layout is identical.

On the webpage, this is as simple as clicking the radio button located beside text "RW B".

I've been attempting to get the macro to latch on to the previous TD with innerhtml "RW B" and then click the INPUT item within the next TD tag.

So far, I've tried the following with no success:

1

```
For Each ele In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("span")
    If ele.innerHTML Like "RW B" Then
         ele.NextSibling.FireEvent ("onclick")
    End If
Next
```

2

```
For Each ele In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("span")
    If ele.innerHTML Like "RW B" Then
         ele.NextSibling.Children(0).FireEvent ("onclick")
    End If
Next
```

3

```
Var element = objIE.Document.querySelector("input[onclick^='SetAccessLevel('B','RW'']")
```

4

```
For Each ele In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("td").
    If ele.innerHTML Like "RW B" Then
         ele.NextSibling(0).Firevent ("onclick")
     End If
Next
```

I've also tried variations of element.Focus, element.Click instead of the FireEvent method.

Any help is appreciated because I've spent too many hours trying to get this to work. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Here's more HTML code from the page -

```
<DIV style="BORDER-TOP-STYLE: ridge; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: ridge; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: ridge; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: ridge"><TABLE width="98%">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD width="25%"><SPAN style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Group Name</SPAN></TD>
<TD width="25%"><SPAN style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold; align: center">Access Rights</SPAN></TD>
<TD width="15%"><SPAN style="align: center"></SPAN></TD>
<TD width="25%"><SPAN style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Owners</SPAN></TD>
<TD width="15%"><SPAN style="align: center"></SPAN></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD width="25%"><SPAN>Group RW B</SPAN></TD>
<TD width="25%"><SPAN>RW B</SPAN></TD>
<TD width="15%"><INPUT onclick="SetAccessLevel('B', 'RW');" id=Ctrl_59296626_ctl95 type=radio value=ctl95 name=Ctrl_59296626$GroupAccess></TD>
```

Comment: Go for input. `getElementsByTagName("input")(number)` Here the number should be the `number of occurrence of input - 1`

Comment: @Tehscript: Thanks, I considered that but the number of input elements varies by page. Some have a few (RW A to RW C) whereas some have many, all the way until RW H. Moreover, the position of the RW B radio button varies. Any other ideas?

Comment: try `Checked = True` for the first example

Comment: Just tried that, but did not work. The macro runs without an error but I still wonder if the code I'm using references the object accurately. Any ideas?.

Comment: As far as I can see you are trying to click the span element instead of input element. Because it doesn't look like a Sibling from what you have shared. If the input is not a child of span, then you can't go with span innertext. Can you post the outer html of the whole radio buttons up to the outer div?

Comment: Thanks @Tehscript, I've updated the question, please have a look.